# getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow Hartl's Rails Tutorial, but running into problems on chapter two.

[I'm at this section](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-demo_users_resource) and do everything up till this point...

```
$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT    # Use only `rails server` if running locally
```

To which it gives me an error....

```
/home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:459:in `tcp_server_sockets'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:133:in `listen'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:114:in `initialize'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carson/Ruby/rortutorial/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/carson/Ruby/rortutorial/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/carson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carson/Ruby/rortutorial/toy_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/carson/Ruby/rortutorial/toy_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I really don't know much of...what is going on to actually debug this or where to begin, any help?